# Are requests always processed sequentially by a server?

Tags: sockets, networking, server, interactive-brokers

I'm currently programming to Interactive Broker's TWS API. It's a socket based trading API that allows me to #placeOrder at the broker and request the current state (#reqOpenOrders). 
So if i place an order and before getting a status response the client gets disconnected, I have no idea if the request was received and/or processed by the server. The only way to know is to request the current order state and to check if the new order is represented. If so, then I do not need to place the order again. However, this requires that the original #placeOrder request is always fully processed and represented in the server's state, before any other requests are peocessed by the server. Otherwise the #reqOpenOrders may return the state before the #placeOrder request was processed.

I can't find anything about sequential processing of the message flow, so can this generally be assumed? If not, how can I ensure that I don't send duplicate order requests after timeouts/disconnects?